# Do closures store global variables?

Tags: javascript, variables, scope, global-variables, environment

According to MDN,

"A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment within which that function was declared. This environment consists of any local variables that were in-scope at the time the closure was created."

What is it meant by "local variables"? Do closures store global variables that are available to a function, too, when it is created? Or do they only store local variables from any functions enclosing the current function?

If closures for some reason store global variables, wouldn't that be a lot of information to store for each closure (like in a large file with lots of variables)?

Comment: No, storing a global variable isn't needed, because a global variable can't be removed. "Local variable" is a variable declared inside a function, including the arguments of the function. Normally these are garbage collected after the function has been executed, but if you're returning ex. a function referring one or more local variables, the referred variables are stored in a closure, and are not garbage collected.

Comment: May you share some code to further your question?

Comment: Open [this jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pdt17cnr/1/) in Chrome. Open the console and run the snippet. In the console, click the triangle in front of the object, and again in front of `setLocal` method. Open `[[Scopes]]` branch, and you'll see the _references_ to the lexical environments bound to this method. Index 0 contains the variables stored in the closures, but the global `glob` is not included in the list, instead, you can find it from 1: Script. 0 is bound to the function, but 1 and 2 are only references to the stored values in the outer scope, they're common to all functions.

Comment: Chrome or Chromium-based DevTools is needed to see `[[Scopes]]`, this feature is not implemented in the console of Firefox or IE.

Comment: Thanks, @Teemu. So global variables aren't stored in closures (because there isn't any reason to do so) and only _referred_ local variables are stored in closures (not all available local variables). Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. However, there are a lot of ways to create memory leaks with closures. For example, if we'd pass an object to `scope` in the linked snippet, and then closed over a single property only, the entire object would be stored in the closure ([see it here](https://jsfiddle.net/dcfvqm4t/)). You can imagine how this effects when you'll pass a 1 MB data object to a function ... To tackle the issue, read the properties for closures into variables, and then include the variables in the return value instead of a direct reference to the passed object.

Comment: +1 for this question that's meant to explain a little-confusing-at-first-reading part of the documentation from MDN

Answer (score 0):

Yes. It does somewhere in the memory.

```js
function outer() {
 let apple = "fruit";
 function inner() {
   console.log(apple);
 }
 return inner;
}
let accessInner = outer();
accessInner();
```

The value of closure here is "fruit".
After you invoke the outer(), the return value of inner() assigns to accessInner varialble as a function object.
It means accessInner.[[environment]] stored the value "fruit" passing from outer().
Since the accessInner variable is in global EC, it stores as kind of strict global variable.